# How do I both annotate the nodes of a tree and color certain branches with ggtree?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, phylogeny, ggtree

I want to annotate a `phylogenetic tree` with `bootstrap` scores and add color to certain `clades` in `ggtree`. Something goes wrong when I try to do both, which has something to do with the indices of the internal nodes.

Here is a random tree with `24 tips`:

```r
library(ape)
set.seed(123)
rtree <- rtree(24)
```

The following identifies the nodes to which I want to assign different colors:

```r
library(ggtree)
rtree.clade <- groupClade(rtree, c(44, 37, 29))
```

These are the scores with which I want to annotate the tree:

```r
rtree.bs <- c(1000,  918,  966,  997,  661,  631,  711, 1000,  980,  991,  999,  998, 1000, 1000,  990, 1000,  980, 1000, 899, 755, 654, 908, 334)
```

In the following two trees, the bootstrap scores do not show up on the same nodes:

```r
#Tree with color added to clades
ggtree(rtree.clade, aes(color = group)) +
geom_tiplab() +
geom_nodelab(label = rtree.bs, geom = 'label')
#Tree with no color
ggtree(rtree.clade) +
geom_tiplab() +
geom_nodelab(label = rtree.bs, geom = 'label')
```

In the tree without color, the bootstrap scores have been assigned to the correct nodes. It is the tree with color that is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?